# ¿Por qué mysql_num_rows me devuelve 1 si no hay registros en la tabla de la base de datos?

Tags: php, sql

Esta es la consulta..

```
$consulta="select count(*) from sap_client_price where f_mat_id='G017-500366' and f_comp_id='GE2000' and f_cus_id='DIMAICA'";
$existe= mysql_query($consulta);
//arregla la consulta y pon la condicion de SI ese registro ya existe.
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($existe); 
echo "</br>$num_rows</br>";
```

esta es la tabla en la DB

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es la salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si te manda 1 y no tienes datos, algo debes estar haciendo mal, para que la consulta te lea 1 dato por algun lugar

Comment: No esta haciendo nada mal, el resultado es correcto.

Answer (score 4):

Un `SELECT COUNT(*)` siempre devuelve un registro aunque no haya datos en la tabla

```
$consulta="select count(*) as total from sap_client_price where f_mat_id='G017-500366' and f_comp_id='GE2000' and f_cus_id='DIMAICA'";
$existe= mysql_query($consulta);
//arregla la consulta y pon la condicion de SI ese registro ya existe.
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($existe); 
$fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)
echo "</br>Total de Registros :$num_rows  ,  Total del count : $fila['total'] </br>";
```

Comment: no, de hecho no

Comment: siempre no, cuando no hay registro devuelve 0, cuando encuentra uno devuelve 1

Comment: @Critical Ghost estas en un error. SELECT COUNT SIEMPRE devuelve un registro que es la cantidad de los que cuadren con el WHERE. Si hay alguno devuelve n, si no hay ninguno devuelve 0 pero eso ya es un registro

Comment: pues ami me devuelve 0 siempre, cuando no tengo registros pero bueno XD

Comment: el resultado es cero pero el total de registro es uno, en este caso el esta consultando y pregunta por el total de registro

Comment: Estas confundiendo que te devuelva el valor 0 con que no te devuelva nada.

Comment: entonces señor @JackNavaRow la consulta esta bien

Comment: la consulta esta bien pero debe preguntar por la columna no por el total de registros

Comment: @JackNavaRow planeas contar las columnas????

Comment: Lo que quiere decir es que no tiene que sacar el numero de registros obtenidos sino el valor del COUNT

Comment: gracias @Lithorell

Comment: @Lithorell me das permiso para editar tu respuesta

Comment: @JackNavaRow no se puede, no tiene los suficienters caracters para la modificacion

Comment: Adelante @JackNavaRow

Answer (score 4):

Con `$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($existe);` devuelve el número de filas en los resultados de la consulta pasada como argumento, ten en cuenta que al realizar un `select count` esta devuelve una fila con el número de resultado de la consulta. Es decir que da igual el número de resultados que devuelva el select, siempre devolverá una fila con el número de resultados de la consulta sean 0 o 1000. Así que `$num_rows` siempre será 1.

Podrías modificar el count por el nombre de un campo en la consulta de ese modo el resultado son las filas que cumplen la condición del where. Así:

```
$consulta="select id from sap_client_price where f_mat_id='G017-500366' and f_comp_id='GE2000' and f_cus_id='DIMAICA'";
```

También podrías seguir con el count pero no contabilizar el número de filas devueltas sino leer el resultado de la consulta. Así:

```
$consulta="select count(*) from sap_client_price where f_mat_id='G017-500366' and f_comp_id='GE2000' and f_cus_id='DIMAICA'";
$existe= mysql_query($consulta);

$fila = mysql_fetch_array($existe, MYSQL_NUM);
echo "</br>$fila[0]</br>";
```

Comment: esta respuesta es mas completa que la otra.. pero la sugerencia no es buena (que pasa si esa consulta devuelve miles de registros?)

Comment: @gbianchi tienes razón, he editado mi respuesta añadiendo otra sugerencia aunque claro eso depende de cual sea su objetivo en el programa.